# Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to pass existing connection to DbContext, but I get this error:

> Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var oracleConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
        {
            using (var conn = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var context = new MainDbContext(conn, false))
                {
                    var cmd = @" some sql commandd here ...";
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="OracleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASS" />
```

Comment: Are you sure your `oracleConnectionString` is right?

Comment: Show your connection string.

Comment: I added connection string to question.

Comment: Do you have the Entity Framework edmx in a different project that the calling project - or is it all one project?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: the syntax of connection string is correct.

Comment: I tried to add provider name like this - <add name="OracleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASS"  providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>, but that didn't help.
And yes, edmx file is in another project.

Comment: You need to add the connection string to the calling project.

Comment: Check post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184799/unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-for-provider-factory-of-type-npgsql-npgsq/28660882#28660882
It solved my similar problem with SQLite DB.

Comment: Check post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184799/unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-for-provider-factory-of-type-npgsql-npgsq/28660882#28660882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Database First, looks like you can't create new DbContext from Oracle connection string, because EF doesn't know, where to look for metadata. You need to use EF connection, instead of Oracle connection. This is what solved it for me:

```
var efConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDbContext"].ConnectionString;
using (var conn = new EntityConnection(efConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var context = new MainDbContext(conn, false))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have your `edmx` file in a different class project, to say your web project, you also need to have the same connection string in the web project.

so...

**Class Project**:

- edmx file
- App.Config (connection string for edmx file)

**Web Project**

- Web.Config (same connection string as above.)

Also, take a look here [Problems switching .NET project from unmanaged to managed ODP.NET assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395002/problems-switching-net-project-from-unmanaged-to-managed-odp-net-assemblies) in case you're missing some Oracle 
assemblies.

Comment: I tried to do that, but unfortunately that didn't help. Also, I need to use OracleConnection, so I think I need Oracle connection string, not .edmx file connection string (the one with 'metadata=res:// ...')

Comment: Add the Oracle connection in too.

Comment: Also did that. Now I have both connection strings in App/Web .config
    <add name="MainDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.EfDataModel.csdl|res://*/EF.EfDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EF.EfDataModel.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;password=PASS;persist security info=True;user id=USER&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="OracleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASS" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>